# Convergence of a power series at a point

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose a power series $\sum a_n z^n$ with $a_n,z \in \mathbb{C}$ converges for some single point $z_0$ in the complex plane.

Can we then say that it converges on any disk with radius $r\leq |z_0|$? I think **yes** since the power series has a radius of convergence, say $R$, where the series converges for $|z|<R$ and diverges for$ |z|>R$. So, since the series converges at a single point, R must be 'big enough' to include this point.

Am I correct in my thinking?

Comment: it converges for any $|z| < R$ but it doesn't have to converge at any other point on $|z| = R$. In general, a power series converges on $|z| < r$  and diverges for $|z| > r$ for some $r$ (possibly $ r = \infty$ or $r = 0$), but everything is possible on $|z| = r$ (converges nowhere, everywhere, only at some points)

Comment: What would be an example as in your first sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can affirm that converges in a disk with $r<|z_0|$. Not equal. For example, $\sum \frac{1}{n}z^n$ converges for all $z\in \{z:|z|\leq 1\}-\{1\}$, but with $z=1$ diverges.

Then, if $z_0=i$, don't have convergency in the disk with $r=1$

Comment: That example is not quite what I am looking for, since your series diverges for all |z|=1.

Comment: Does the power series converge for $z=i?$

Comment: @Dman You say $\sum(-1)^n\frac1n$ diverges? Hmm...

Comment: @Dman converges. Use dirichlet's criterion

Comment: @vvnitram Your example and answer is correct, and thus +1 . Yet, if instead $\;i\;$ you'd choose $\;z_0=-1\;$ perhaps things could have gone smoother, as the alternating Harmonic series is the standard (or almost) example of (convergent, of course) Leibniz series.